# Merge 2 sql files

Tags: sql, files

i made a backup of a old sql database and wont overwrite the new one. is that a way i can merge them?

Comment: What database platform?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Progress, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes. But it depends what kind of db format you have. If you have simple text file with SQL statements, you can use unix tools like awk, grep, diff, etc. Or you can use perl it should simplify the problem.
Depends of your database type, backup type and size.